# How should I test a wrapper I wrote for a Socket?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, udp, wrapper

So, as part of this Source Engine project, I wrote a class that's basically a socket wrapper.   I wanted to unit test it (it's going to end up being a gem I release when it's done, so it should be tested)

The problem is...I'm -really- new to unit testing, and I don't really know how I should test this thing.

Relevant code is here:
https://github.com/misutowolf/freeman/blob/master/lib/source_socket.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would say you should probably raise exceptions when unexpected args come in to the constructor. Assuming you are returning exceptions, testing is actually really simple for this class. This should get you started:

```
# spec/lib/source_socket_spec.rb

describe SourceSocket do

  subject { source_socket }

  let(:source_socket) { SourceSocket.new(address, port, buffer) }

  let(:address) { double :address, class: SourceAddress, ip:   '1.2.3.4' }
  let(:port)    { double :port,    class: SourcePort,    num:  9876      }
  let(:buffer)  { double :buffer,  class: SourceBuffer                   }

  describe '#new' do
    context 'when the arguments are of the correct types' do
      it 'assigns the expected variables' do
        subject
        assigns(:address).should eq '1.2.3.4'
        assigns(:buffer).should  eq buffer
        assigns(:port).should    eq 9876
      end
    end

    context 'when the arguments are of incorrect types' do
      context 'when the address is of incorrect type' do
        let(:address) { double :address }
        expect { subject }.to raise_error('Error: Address argument is wrong type.')
      end

      context 'when the port is of incorrect type' do
        let(:port)    { double :port    }
        expect { subject }.to raise_error('Error: Port argument is wrong type.')
      end

      context 'when the buffer is of incorrect type' do
        let(:buffer)  { double :buffer  }
        expect { subject }.to raise_error('Error: Buffer must be a SourceBuffer object!')
      end
    end
  end

  describe '#to_s' do
    its(:to_s) { should eq '1.2.3.4:9876' }
  end

  describe '#open' do
    subject { source_socket.open(engine) }
    let(:engine) { double(:engine) }

    let(:socket) { double(:socket, connect: nil) }
    let(:packed) { double(:packed) }

    before do
      Socket.stub(:new).and_return(socket)
      Socket.stub(:pack_sockaddr_in).and_return(packed)
    end

    it 'assigns the engine variable' do
      subject
      assigns(:engine).should_not be_nil
    end

    it 'instantiates a Socket' do
      Socket.should_receive(:new).with(Socket::PF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM)
      subject
    end

    it 'assigns the socket variable' do
      subject
      assigns(:socket).should_not be_nil
    end

    it 'packs up the port and host' do
      Socket.should_receive(:pack_sockaddr_in).with(9876, '1.2.3.4')
      subject
    end

    it 'connects the socket' do
      socket.should_receive(:connect).with(packed)
    end
  end
end
```

Just keep in mind there are many ways to test, and the [RSpec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec) are your best friend.

Comment: Yeah, I need to really get used to RSpec.   This is my first serious Ruby project, and I was originally going to use TDD, and got intimidated by not knowing the testing framework.

I've never done unit testing in any other language I've ever played with, so I guess I didn't have any sort of reference to learn from, either.  Thanks a ton, I'll definitely mess with this.

I think the biggest problem I have personally is understanding mock objects and doubles and stuff.